# Make jqZoom Evolution's zoom box follow my mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jqZoom](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/) Evolution to implement zoom functionality on my site, the problem is that it does not have the functionality for the zoom box to follow my mouse pointer around as I hover over a image, I have tried using mousemove to make it follow the cursor around, but every time I resize the browser the box moves further away from the cursor,

```
    $("#single_main_container").mousemove(function(e){

        $(".zoomWindow").css({
            top: e.pageY,
            left: e.pageX
        });

    });
```

so basically I just need the zoom box to follow my mouse cursor around when I hover over the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not following your cursor?
but the 1st demo is showing zoom as you move your mouse
http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo1

**Edit**

not exactly a solution but an alternative plugin which provides mouseover zoom out-of-box

http://redeyeoperations.com/plugins/zoomy/

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question and posted the answer in a hurry..maybe you the looking for a way to make "box with zoomed image" follow your cursor

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! I am going to try and implement it now! I will post back!

Comment: It definitely did the trick, I will need to customize it a bit for my specific needs, but it's a lifesaver! Thanks for the help! :)